# Is meher payable even after a divorce demanded by wife?

Tags: nikah, talaq, mehr

Sometimes the *meher* is not given, or is not given in full, at the time of marriage, rather the man promises to provide the *meher* at some later date.

This question regards the situation where the wife demands a divorce from her husband, and the husband decides to let her go: Is providing the complete *meher* still compulsory for the man?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Jafari Fiqh Mahr is her right, to which her husband remains indebted unless woman forgive it (for example in case of Khul divorce or Mubarat divorce)

And should be paid in any situation and even can be asked to be paid legally by sue. Unless the woman forgive it willingly. But this may depend on laws of each country. For example in Iran the amount of meher is registered in marriage document as a legal document and the woman can sue husband for not paying it before or after the divorce. It is like any other legal debt.

Islam recommends to meher be paid as soon as possible even if no divorce happen as well as any other debt. There are some Hadith saying remaining under debt is Makrook (disliked by Islam).

Ref:

http://www.al-islam.org/marriage-handbook/6.htm#6

Quran says:

> وَآتُوا النِّسَاءَ صَدُقَاتِهِنَّ نِحْلَةً ۚ فَإِن طِبْنَ لَكُمْ عَن
>   شَيْءٍ مِّنْهُ نَفْسًا فَكُلُوهُ هَنِيئًا مَّرِيئًا
>
> [[4:4] Sahih International](http://tanzil.net/#4:4)
>
> And give the women [upon marriage] their [bridal] gifts graciously.
>   But if they give up willingly to you anything of it, then take it in
>   satisfaction and ease.

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate @Ahmadi's research and answer but, I wasn't 100% satisfied. I would like to extend the answer further.

I have got 2 different perspectives according to both perspectives the Mahr should be given to the bride even after divorce (even if it is demanded by wife).

First perspective:

It is best to give Mahr at the time of marriage. If you can not, then it becomes a due on you. So, even if you get divorced (no matter who initiated) the due amount should be given to the bride.

Second perspective:
If you don't give Mahr at the time of marriage then you **promise** to give it later.
According to the first verse of Surah al-Ma'idah, Allah called upon the believers:

> "O you who believe! Fulfill your promises." [5:1] : [source](http://www.islamformankind.com/downloads/promise.html)

So, no matter if you  you get divorced, you have to fulfill your promise.